# Equalizers exist in an Abelian category

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I'm trying to show that equalizers exist in an Abelian category. I am trying to follow a proof my professor did in class, but it's hazy. I understand we first consider the monomorphisms $(1,f),(1,g):A \longrightarrow B$ and then consider their intersection. After that, I'm a little lost. I'm new to category theory, so if you could please use simple and explicit terminology that would be great!

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Abelian categories have kernels. An equalizer of $f,g:A\to B$ is thus the kernel of $f-g$.

Explicitly, let $k:K\to A$ be a kernel of $f-g$. Then $(f-g)\circ k=0$. Moreover, if $\ell:L\to A$ is such that $(f-g)\circ \ell=0$, then there exists a unique $u:L\to K$ such that $\ell=k\circ u$.

Unravelling the paragraph above, the equation $(f-g)\circ k=0$ is equivalent to $f\circ k=g\circ k$. Moreover if $\ell:L\to A$ is such that $f\circ\ell=g\circ \ell$, then there exists a unique $u:L\to K$ such that $\ell=k\circ u$. Hence $k:K\to A$ satisfies the universal property of an equilizer of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: I realize this, however it's not the type of proof I'm looking for. Thank you thought.

Comment: Did you need more details? What sort of proof are you interested in?

Comment: That proof makes a lot of sense, and I'm familiar with that terminology $f-g$ from other texts. However, the proof I'm looking for uses the very basic ideas of products and intersections to pop out the existence of the equalizer for a pair of morphisms, instead of relying on "difference of morphisms."

Comment: What are you using as the definition of an abelian category? What text are you using?

Comment: I'm using the definition that 1) a zero object exists, 2) every morphism has a kernel and cokernel, 3) every monomorphism is a kernel of some morphism (hence of its cokernel), 4) every epimorphism is a cokernel of some morphism (hence of its kernel), 5) any two objects have a product and a coproduct.

Comment: No text is currently official for the class, however I'm studying Freyd's "Abelian Categories", Herrlich's "Category Theory", ALuffi's "Algebra: Chapter 0".

Comment: Hi @boldbrandywine. You should work out the equivalence of definitions in this case between "$\mathcal{C}$ has biproducts" and "you can add/subtract morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$", that is, it is pre-additive, or additive. It only takes a few lines and is helpful!

Comment: @redfiloux I wouldn't say it only takes a few lines. There are lots of things to check, not least the existence of additive inverses, which is very non-obvious.

Comment: I would like to be able to prove it without knowledge of morphism subtraction. Instead I'd like to use the very basics (products/intersections) to prove the existence of equalizers. In a sense, diagram chasing.